# como disponibilizar mais de um arquivo para download com apenas um botão em HTML

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Gostaria de saber se em HTML é possível fazer download de mais de um arquivo (foto no caso) estou usando o botão do bootstrap e fiz o seguinte código :

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="images/cant3.png" download="cant3.png" ; >Baixe nosso Cardápio Físico</a>
```

mas eu gostaria que ao clicar fosse feito o download de 2 imagens, alguém pode me ajudar??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que a melhor solução no caso de um cardápio é juntar as duas imagens em uma só. Considere fazer um pdf.

Existe uma solução que talvez não seja tão elegante, mas como já resolvi um problema similar assim vou postar, e se alguém colocar uma resposta mais "elegante" considere ela.

Você pode colocar outro download para ser feito junto com JavaScript.

```js
function dowload(){
  document.getElementById('btn_imagem2').click();
}
```

```html
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="images/cant3.png" download="cant3.png" onclick="dowload()">Baixe nosso Cardápio Físico</a>
<!--Aqui é a segunda imagem que pretende fazer o dowload-->
<a id="btn_imagem2" class="btn btn-primary" href="images/cant4.png" download="cant4.png" hidden="true">Baixe nosso Cardápio Físico</a>
```

Assim quando o usuário clicar no botão 1, você força ele clicar no botão 2, que ele nem esta vendo (perceba a propriedade hidden="true").
isto vai fazer os dois evento de download serem disparados.